# Maven Checkstyle Plugin - Test XREF

Tags: maven-2, checkstyle

My maven reports are working great, all except Checkstyle and test xref.  My test source is still being cross referenced at xref and not the test xref.  So, when I click on the xref from within a Checkstyle report, I naturally get an error, the file isn't found.  If I click on a source file, it works perfectly.

I tried testXrefLocation in the configuration to no avail.  Is this by design, or am I missing a configuration?

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <enableRulesSummary>false</enableRulesSummary>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                    <configLocation>${project.build.directory}/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <testXrefLocation>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/xref-test</testXrefLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


mvn clean install site
```

In my target directory where all this stuff is generated, I have both xref and xref-test.  However, my checkstyle reports for my test source code are still linked to target/xref and not target/xref-test.

Also, FYI, I am using a lot of inheritance to reduce the amount of configuration in a single Maven POM.  Therefore, this plugin belongs to a parent pom which declares which plugins I want to use for testing.  I have another that says I want to generate javadoc and source in addition to the compiled code.

Walter

Comment: I removed the `[maven-plugin]` tag which is specifically used for maven plugin development.

Comment: could you show at least the build part (source folders etc) and the checkstyle plugin config from your maven pom.xml? Also the exact maven commands you are using and your maven version?

Comment: Did you get a chance to see my pom?  Do you have any additional questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up removing this configuration in favor of using Sonar since it gives me much more information with a nicer UI.